# jquary drag drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> После переноса зелёного квадрата при нажатии на него она должна
>   вернутся назад как это сделать?

```js
function makeDroppable(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragBlock(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.id);
}

function dropBlock(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //При извлечении данных Вы должны использовать такой же тип как и при их сохранение
  var rdata = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  //Очистим содержимое перетаскиваемого элемента
  e.target.innerHTML = "";
  //Сделаем перетаскиваемый элемент элементом потомком принимающей области т.е. фактически мы 
  //переносим его в содержимое принимающего его элемента
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(rdata))
}
```

```css
.block-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
.block-2 {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="box" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragBlock(event)" id="draggable-element"></div>
</div>
<div class="block-2" ondrop="dropBlock(event)" ondragover="makeDroppable(event)"></div>
```

Comment: а она не возвращается?

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы появилось желание на него отвечать, а не давайте задание из набора случайных слов

Comment: Я суда зашол конкретные вопросы задавать а не умолять там чтобы помогли.Это не задание это ваши глаза так видят походу.Прочитайте вопрос еще раз.